# How bind events on dynamically created elements in angular 6?

Tags: angular5, angular6

Suppose I have some dynamically created element having class remove & I want to attach a click event. To achieve this I have wriiten js code which is not working. Please give solution, IKf anybody knows.

test.compomnent.html

```
<div #imageList>
</div>
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.remove')
                                  .addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you create these dynamically created elements?

Comment: kindly provide the full codee